# help with java hash map

Tags: java, hashmap

can some one please explain what is happening in the code below and how it ends up with 36?

thanks

**edit** by Amir Rachum

```
public class HashMap2009 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> myMap2009 = 
            new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        myMap2009.put("one", new Integer(1));
        myMap2009.put("three", new Integer(3));
        myMap2009.put("five", new Integer(5));
        myMap2009.put("seven", new Integer(7));
        myMap2009.put("nine", new Integer(9));
        System.out.println(oddOne(myMap2009));
    }
    private static int oddOne(Map<String, Integer> myMap2009) {
        if (myMap2009.isEmpty())
            return 11;
        else {
            Set<String> st = myMap2009.keySet();
            String key = st.iterator().next();
            int num = myMap2009.get(key);
            myMap2009.remove(key);
            return num + oddOne(myMap2009);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you post it here? You may post your code and the site will format it for you if you add an extra 4 spaces indent.

Comment: apologies I only had a image of the coding but if you right click the image and select "view image" it will be full size.

Comment: @Support - multilanguage SO - thanks for editing in my name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simple example of [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion), which results in adding up all the keys in the map one by one and when the map is empty, it adds another 11. This sums up to 36.

Comment: thanks that makes sense,  i see where i was going wrong, as i had it confused with a stack!!

Answer (score 2):

That's a [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) function, that each time it is called, add the value of the first element in the map and then remove it.

If the map is empty it return 11

So: `9+7+5+3+1+11 =` **36** ( 9,7,5,3,1 for each value in the map and 11 for when it is empty )

BTW, this looks to me as a terrible way to teach recursion ( because the map creates too much noise )

A simpler ( and I think more effective ) way would've been:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class ArrayList2009 {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(7);
        list.add(9);
        System.out.println( addOne( list ) );                        
    }
    private static int addOne( List<Integer> list ){
        if ( list.isEmpty() ) {
            return 11;
        } else {
            Iterator<Integer> i = list.iterator();
            int num = i.next();
            i.remove();
            return num + addOne( list );
        }
    }
}
```

Which does exactly the same, but introduce less noise because the List interface easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

When calling oddOne it will get

- the first number
- remove the number
- add it to the result of oddOne (with the number removed)

this repeats till empty whne oddOne return 11

so we end up with

1 + (3 + (5 + (7 + (9 + 11)))) = 36

actually the order will e all jumbled up as it is a hashmap but this has no influence on adding numbers

Answer (score 0):

You're making recursive calls, removing one element from the map per call.

You could start out with num == 1 (a map is unordered) and you remove this from your map. Then you do the recursive call, which gives you num == 3. This continues until your map is empty, which results in 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9, and an additional 11 for your empty map.

Take a look at recursion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

Comment: Thanks guys, really appreciate all the help.